# Searching parameters with "AND" and "OR"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

here's a example how the program works (for now)

[image: data]

For example if the user search for the word "apple", the program will search for the word "apple" and passed the entire row plus the header onto a new sheet. Like this,

[image]

noticed those two rows having the word "apple" got passed onto a new sheet, this is fine. But now, i am trying to implement a way to search for both words in a single row and for that to be achieved, i think the best way to do it is to use "AND" and "OR" function.

meaning if the user search for both "apple" and "pear" then the first row (plus the header) will get passed onto a new sheet instead of previously passing two rows onto a new sheet.

and for the "OR" function, for example if the user choose to search for either one word, for example, "blue" or "purple"(which clearly don't exist in the original data), the program will passed "blue"(entire row + header) but if such cases that both word exist, the program will passed both the row (and header)

this is the current code i am using.

Edited

```
    Dim search1, search2 As String
Dim searchinput As String
Dim searcharray() As String
Dim display As String
Dim y As Long
Dim LastNonEmpty As Integer
Dim rLastCell As Range
 Dim i As Long, nRowsAddePerSheet As Long, nRows As Long, _
    nRowsMax As Long, nSheets As Long

Dim x
 Dim rg As Range, rgF As Range, rgFF As Range

 Dim wks

Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)


LastNonEmpty = -1

searchinput = Application.InputBox("type in please")
searcharray() = Split(searchinput)


'For y = 0 To 2


If searcharray(1) <> "AND" Then
     searcharray(1) = searcharray(2)
  End If
nSheets = Sheets.count
  nRowsMax = ActiveSheet.Rows.count

  For x = 1 To 2 'nSheets

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = Worksheets("testsearch")
    If (Err) Then
      Set wks = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
      wks.Name = "testsearch"
      Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets(x).Activate
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Cells(1).CurrentRegion

    nRows = rg.Rows.count
    nRowsAddePerSheet = 0
    For i = 1 To nRows
          Set rgF = rg.Rows(i).Find(searcharray(0), , xlValues, xlWhole)
   Next

    For i = 1 To nRows
      Set rgFF = rg.Rows(i).Find(searcharray(1), , xlValues, xlWhole)

   Next

   If rgF.Row <> rgFF.Row Then


       If Not rgF Is Nothing Then
        If (nRowsAddePerSheet <= 0) Then
          If (i <> 1) Then
            rg.Rows(1).Copy wks.Range("A" & nRowsMax).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        End If
        End If
        rg.Rows(i).Copy wks.Range("A" & nRowsMax).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        nRowsAddePerSheet = nRowsAddePerSheet + 1
      End If

      Else
      MsgBox "cannot find"
      End If

  Next



  'Next


Set rgFF = Nothing
  Set rgF = Nothing
  Set rg = Nothing
  Set wks = Nothing

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

@L4D2 This program splits the parameters into three words and search them individually (ignoring the word "AND") and when two of the words are found, they will be compared in terms of their row, if both of them exist in the same row, the program will passed them into a new sheet, however i am able to do it but it passes them 3 times in total onto a same sheet. i wonder why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to do something like this:

```
'...
'input string
strSearch = Application.InputBox("Please enter the search string - two words separated by a space")
'split it into words
strParts = Split(strSearch, " ")
countOfWords = UBound(strParts)
'check if user has entered exactly two words
If countOfWords = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have entered only one word"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf countOfWords > 1 Then
    MsgBox "You have entered more than two word"
    Exit Sub
End If

'do something

For i = 1 To nRows
      Set rgF_1 = rg.Rows(i).Find(strParts(0), , xlValues, xlWhole)
      Set rgF_2 = rg.Rows(i).Find(strParts(1), , xlValues, xlWhole)

      If (Not rgF_1 Is Nothing) AND (Not rgF_2 Is Nothing) Then
          ' do something         
      Else If (Not rgF_1 Is Nothing) OR (Not rgF_2 Is Nothing) Then
          ' do something
      End If
Next
```

Comment: is there any way i can do it without having two input application? something like what "prooffreader" says, checking for space and such.

Comment: sure, you can do this. I've change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Allow your users to enter in more than one word (separated by a space, perhaps) in strSearch. Then check strStearch with InStr to see if it contains a space (you may want to make sure it does not contain more than one). If it does, then split strSearch into two variables, the string to the left of the space and the string to the right of the space (with LEFT, RIGHT and INSTR). You're already using strSearch2 as your worksheet name, so let's call the right string (if it exists) strSearchB, and redefine strSearch as the left string.

Now you can declare another range, rgFB, to search for strSearchB (if it exists) and in your loop have the declaration

```
If Not rgF Is Nothing Or If Not rgFB Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time debugging your code so i made a version of it.
See below:

**Main Sub:**
This checks for the input and decides if it is correct.
It also decides whether to execute `AND sub` or the `OR sub`
(depending on the delimiter used during input)
Only accepts 2 words, no more, no less.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim search_rng As Range, lastcell As Range
Dim lrow As Long
Dim search_size As Boolean
Dim search_input As String
Dim search_string As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set search_rng = ws.Range("A1:D4")
Set lastcell = search_rng.Cells(search_rng.Cells.count)

search_input = InputBox("Enter word(s) you want to search." & vbNewLine & _
                        "Note: Separate by comma for AND, semi-colon for OR")

If InStr(search_input, ",") > 0 Then
    search_string = Split(search_input, ",")
    search_size = IIf(UBound(search_string) = 1, True, False)
    If search_size Then
        ANDSearch search_string(0), search_string(1), search_rng, lastcell
    Else
        MsgBox "You entered to many arguments"
        Exit Sub
    End If
ElseIf InStr(search_input, ";") > 0 Then
    search_string = Split(search_input, ";")
    search_size = IIf(UBound(search_string) = 1, True, False)
    If search_size Then
        ORSearch search_string, search_rng, lastcell
    Else
        MsgBox "You entered to many arguments"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid input"
End If

End Sub
```

**Supporting Sub (And):**
This copies all rows with both words.

```
Private Sub ANDSearch(my_search1 As Variant, my_search2 As Variant, _
                        my_range As Range, end_cell As Range)

Dim foundcell As Range, sub_range As Range
Dim firstaddr As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim check As Boolean
Dim count As Integer

count = 0
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

Set foundcell = my_range.Find(my_search1, end_cell, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
    firstaddr = foundcell.Address
End If

Do Until foundcell Is Nothing
    '~~>just based on your sample data, change column number or make it dynamic
    Set sub_range = foundcell.EntireRow.Resize(, 4)
    check = IsError(Application.Match(my_search2, sub_range, 0))
    If Not check Then
        If count = 0 Then my_range.Resize(1).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
        sub_range.Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0)
        count = count + 1
    End If

    Set foundcell = my_range.FindNext(foundcell)
    If foundcell.Address = firstaddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    Set sub_range = Nothing
Loop

End Sub
```

**Supporting sub (OR):**
This copies all occurences of the words in a row.

```
Private Sub ORSearch(my_search As Variant, my_range As Range, end_cell As Range)

Dim count As Integer, i As Integer
Dim foundcell As Range, sub_range As Range
Dim firstaddr As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

count = 0
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

For i = LBound(my_search) To UBound(my_search)

    Set foundcell = my_range.Find(my_search(i), end_cell, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns)

    If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
        firstaddr = foundcell.Address
        If count = 0 Then my_range.Resize(1).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
        count = count + 1
    End If

    Do Until foundcell Is Nothing
        Set sub_range = foundcell.EntireRow.Resize(, 4)
        sub_range.Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0)
        Set foundcell = my_range.FindNext(foundcell)
        If foundcell.Address = firstaddr Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Next

End Sub
```

This do exactly what you described or almost.
Haven't done a lot of testing.
Kinda rough code and slow execution but at least this might give you a hint to accomplish what you want.
Also the `OR sub` have limitations.
For example the input `apple;pear` results to this:

[image]

since it outputs all occurrences of each word.
I don't know what you want, you did not include it in your question.
If somehow, you don't want entries to be repeated, then tweak the `OR sub` following the logic of `AND sub` after it is done with the first word.

Comment: just trying to find out, after i made the searches, are they gonna display on a new sheet named after the search? for example "apple,pear". New sheet can be named "apple,pear"...and..i have more data rather than A1 to D4 (sorry about not mentioning earlier), can you make a loop on row.count ?? thank you...

Comment: nope, as i've said, i didn't pattern it to your code and instead re-created it based on how i understand what you need. I think you can manage to tweak it your self if you decide to adapt with my code. If i have time, i'll try to revise it a little bit. but i hope you can beat me to that... :)

Comment: i tried working on it, i've tried using array to do it. i managed to get an idea on how to work on it, but i'm screwed as i was.